# How to get HTTP reponse code for Google Custom Search - service.cse().siterestrict().list

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search

I have the following code,

```
service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
        res = service.cse().siterestrict().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
```

need to evaluate the HTTP response( 200, 403 and so on)  - how do I get this?

this gives me the status - is there any better way?

```
 print (service._http.connections['https:www.googleapis.com']._HTTPConnection__response.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did -

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

try:
   #<logic here>
    except HttpError as err:
        if err.resp.status in [400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 409, 410, 411, 412, \
                                413, 416, 417, 428, 429, 500, 501, 502, 503]
            print(msg + traceback.format_exc())
            print ("from exception"+ str(service._http.connections['https:www.googleapis.com']._HTTPConnection__response.status))

        else: raise 

    except Exception as e:
        print(msg + traceback.format_exc())
```

Share if there are more elegant solutions.